# JQuery `.load()` function not executing javascript which is in loading page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

What I'm trying to do is load an external html file and have the Javascript that is embedded execute along with the html code that I had in my `Loading_Page.html`.

The code I'm trying to use is this:

```
$("#myBtn").click(function() {
  $("#myDiv").load("Loading_Page.html");
});
```

Loading_Page.html looks like this (simple now, but will expand once/if I get this working).It has both html and javascript, so I need to get Html page along with the javascript.

```
<html> 
<head>
  <title>Tracking HTML File</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert("outside the jQuery ready");
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="first_division"><img src="someimage.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div id="second_division"><p>some text</p></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But the javascript in Loading_Page.html page is not executing along with the html code in Loading_Page Any thoughts on why the browser is ignoring the Javascript in the Loading_Page.html file?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

jQuery load will just exclude that script tag from response, before it is inserted into a div.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359763/ajax-loaded-content-script-is-not-executing/12360084) question. The same problem happens there.

Comment: Yeah..I had gone through that question.. Can you please say what to do, to resolve this issue

Comment: Instead of load - you can try to use `$.ajax` and in success handler - insert returned HTML into `$("#myDiv")` with `.html()`

Comment: Something like this:  `$.ajax({
  url: 'Loading_Page.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data);
  }
});`

Comment: So can I use anything like $.getScript("javascript.js") as a call back function for load apart from $.ajax to get javascript along with loading html page...??

Comment: Hm. Yes. But actually - I do not think you should do that. This `$("#myDiv").html(data)` or at least `$("#myDiv")[0].innerHTML = data;` should execute JS (in $.ajax success handler). In that case it was not possible to do like that because OP were trying to take only a part of response.

Comment: So in that case I will use   $.ajax({ url: 'Loading_Page.html', success: function(data) { $("#myDiv").html(data); } });  only. Thanks for your valuable reply and patience.

Comment: Yes. That is what I'm saying about. Just try it on your example code and see if it works. There could be problems with head, body tags inside resulting elements.