# AJAX callback not refreshing page

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

Hi guys I have a problem where by I am doing an AJAX callback:

```
var htmlToInject;
        function Next(step) {
            var options = {
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: "Page.aspx?Page=" + step,
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result) {                   
                    htmlToInject = result;                  
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {                   
                },
                complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {                  
                    $("#form1").empty();
                    $("#form1").append(htmlToInject);                  
                }
            };
            $.ajax(options);
        }
```

But the problem lies in where I am using jQuery validation methods and I am creating controls dynamically. So the callback does not cause a post back so controls would not be generated, which I solved by doing this:

```
                        $("#form1").empty();
                        $("#form1").append(htmlToInject);
```

Which then displayed the newly generated controls.

But validation on the fields is giving me errors: 'settings' is null.

I took a look at the page source and the source was there for the previously generated controls. I do not want to post back as I do not want the "loading" effect, hence why I am using ajax.

How can I over come this issue guys?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using unobtrusive ajax you can do this in the success/complete function as appropriate:

```
$('#form1').html(htmlToInject);
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form1');
```

Comment: getting does not contain unobtrusive property or method error.

Comment: OK - You must be using a different mechanism for wiring up your validation, similar to what FAngel suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> I took a look at the page source and the source was there for the
>   previously generated controls.

If you are talking about Right Click->View Source, than it will show HTML you originaly get from server when page is loaded with regular POST/GET (some browsers may even repeat request to server to get it). If you want to see changes done by JS/AJAX - you need to use developer tools. All modern browsers have that. FireFox may need Firebug to be installed. Just press F12 to see those tools.

> But validation on the fields is giving me errors: 'settings' is null.

I do not see any validation initialization code after you change form content:

```
complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {                  
                    $("#form1").empty();
                    $("#form1").append(htmlToInject);                  
                }
```

You should add `$("#form1").validate({...})` (or how your validation plugin is initialized) again after you have placed new form elements.

Comment: the htmlToInject variable had the $("#form1").validate({...}) part of the set of controls to validate, I checked the source of the page using developer tools and it does not appear there.

Comment: It is removed by jQuery. Try to move it into complete function and see if it will work. Possibly `$("#form1").html(htmlToInject)` will work, but not sure.

Comment: i am doing it in the complete function and its not there at all, and not working.

Comment: What are you doing? As I understand `htmlToInject` contains a piece `<script>...</script>` and you expect that `.append(htmlToInject)` will execute that script, right?

Comment: I don't think you can include javascript in the returned HTML as you are trying (i.e. with type 'html'. This might give you some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235967/calling-a-jquery-function-inside-html-return-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Plus few more similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359763/ajax-loaded-content-script-is-not-executing/12360084#12360084 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692619/jquery-load-function-not-executing-javascript-which-is-in-loading-page

Comment: @FAngel, yes thats correct. htmlToInject contains the <script>...</script> for the jQuery validation for the new set of generated controls.

Comment: Than, see links provided by me and Tim Croydon. jQuery strips out script tags in some cases. Suppose that is what happens in your case. So, you may take a look at those links - possibly something from there will work for you or move validation initialization code into your complete function.